# Problem creating a custom route in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, rest, custom-url

Hello I am having an error whenever I try to create a custom route in WordPress. I am creating my own API and I want to create a custom url route like this:

```
add_action('rest_api_init', 'universityRegisterSearch');

function universityRegisterSearch() {
  register_rest_route('university/v1', 'search', array(
    'methods' => WP_REST_SERVER::READABLE,
    'callback' => 'universitySearchResults'
  ));
}

function universitySearchResults() {
  return 'Congratulations, you created a route.';
}
```

and I keep getting this error every time:

404 Error with Custom URL Route

[image]

This is the url i am testing with: http://fictional-university.local/wp-json/university/v1/search

Is there another solution to this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me you are doing everything correctly. Using your function I can open the custom route, no problem.

[image]
Image Link: https://d.pr/i/5HhqvT

URL: `/wp-json/university/v1/search` - maybe try a conflict check next or maybe your custom function is not properly running.

Kind regards,

Comment: Thanks for the reply! How do I do a conflict check?

Comment: You are welcome. 
For a conflict check, you activate a default theme such as Storefront or Twenty Twenty and only the extension you want to test. So in your case probably none and only leave your custom code active. 

Takes about 5 minutes to test but do take a backup before you get going. 

Here is some documentation by the WooCommerce team:  https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/troubleshooting-using-health-check/ 

You can use https://wordpress.org/plugins/health-check/ for this. It allows you to deactivate all plugins and activate a default theme just for your user session.

Comment: Okay, I will try that. Thanks alot!

Comment: OMGosh i was in the completely wrong file path ‍♂️ - SOLVED